# Do different foods heal different amounts of HP?

Tags: kirby-planet-robobot

There are several types of food healing items in *Kirby: Planet Robobot*. (cherries, ice cream, meat, pineapples, etc)

Aside from the Maxim Tomato which fully heals Kirby, do different food items heal different amounts of HP? Or do all healing items act identically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Kirby wikia](https://kirby.fandom.com/wiki/Meat#Kirby_64:_The_Crystal_Shards.2C_Kirby.27s_Return_to_Dream_Land.2C_Kirby:_Triple_Deluxe.2C_Kirby_Fighters_Deluxe.2C_Kirby:_Planet_Robobot.2C_Team_Kirby_Clash_Deluxe.2C_and_Super_Kirby_Clash):

> Meat is a common food item in the game. It has no special healing value, **healing the same as all the other common food items.**

So, apparently, only special foods have a different effect, like *Maxim Tomato* as you discovered, and also [Reviving Tomato](https://kirby.fandom.com/wiki/Reviving_Tomato):

> Reviving Tomatoes **restore Kirby's Health completely when used**, just like a Maxim Tomato. Reviving Tomatoes have a more impressive power, however; if Kirby has one of these items in storage when he is KO'd, it will **automatically revive him to full health** in a flash. If the pink puff defeats the boss without using his Reviving Tomato, it will transform into an ordinary Maxim Tomato afterwards.

And the [Energy Drink](https://kirby.fandom.com/wiki/Energy_Drink):

> Energy Drinks recover **one-third or two bars of Kirby's Health** instantly, in contrast to **regular food, which restores half** this amount.

Comment: How much do energy drinks restore in Robobot?

Comment: @Stevoisiak since Kirby's health in KPP is a number (called Stamina) and not a set of bars, I'll go for one-third of max health.

Comment: Stamina is seen as a [percentage also for damage calculation](https://wikirby.com/wiki/Stamina), so it makes sense.